# Checking if time has reset in UTC

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking all over for answers regarding this. but can't quite find it.

I'm trying to figure out how I can apply this to code for a vote system: say I voted at 23:00 UTC (11 PM),  and vote resets at 00:00 UTC (12 AM Midnight), I can vote directly after again, but can't vote another time until the reset happens at 00:00 UTC.
This is what I have so far:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$reset = strtotime('today 00:00:00');
$lastDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lasttime)); // last vote time from DB, if not time is present, time() will be used.
$canvote = $reset < $lastDate;
```

so, you can only vote once per reset, rather than once every 24 hours.

Comment: You could just store `date` and not `datetime` in db then have unique constraint for date with userid.

Comment: You can vote when the last vote time is before the last reset: $reset > $lastDate. You can also vote when there was no vote at all before.

Comment: `$canvote = $lastDate >= strtotime("today") && $lastDate < strtotime("tommorow") || $reset > $lastDate;` so something like that? I already have a check to see if they voted at all before. @Henrik

Comment: @Arya As I understand your description in the OP, `$canvote = $reset >= $lastDate` should be enough. Always when the reset is the later event than the last vote, you can vote again.